# Canbus Rx pin shows Tx data

Tags: stm32

I am trying to see some data on the CANBUS line , I show the CANH and CANL data on the osciloscope line. And detect Rx line, When I show the Transmit message on the CANBUS line, I show the this data on RX line at the same time. Why this occurs ? Is that possible, or I have error ?
I am using stm32f4 microcontroller and canbus tranceiver.
[image]

The message we see on the Canbus line CANH-CANL messages are the data I send from the processor to the sensor. Therefore, why is the data I want to send coming back to the Rx line, ACK is added to the end, but only ACK is not required?

And if there is normal situation how does MCU decide to which is Real Rx data and the returned of the sent data with ack. I am so confused about that.